# How can I join two join queries into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm kinda lost here I need to join two join queries to form one table. Here's the script that I'm working on...

```
SELECT Email, Domain, site.SiteID, site.SiteName, Status, LastLogin, up.UPID, up.UPName, trd.TRMCID, trd.TRMCName
FROM UserDetails as ud
INNER JOIN SiteLocation as site
on ud.SiteID = site.SiteID

INNER JOIN UltimateParent as up
on ud.UPID = up.UPID

INNER JOIN TRMCDetails as trd
on ud.TRMCID = trd.TRMCID

SELECT SiteID, cinfo.CountryCode, Country
From Country as cntry
INNER JOIN CountryInfo as cinfo
on cntry.CountryCode = cinfo.CountryCode

INNER JOIN SiteLocation as site2
on cntry.CountryCode = site2.CountryCode
```

I need to show the country but the countrycode is connected with the SiteID. I'm having difficulty to join the both of them.

This is the first table looks like

Email-Domain-SiteID-SiteName-Status-LLogin-UPID-UPName-TRMCID-TRMCName

This is the second table looks like

SiteID-CountryCode-Country

I need the third table to look like this

Email-Domain-SiteID-SiteName-Status-LLogin-UPID-UPName-TRMCID-TRMCName-Country

But, I'm having trouble combining the two joins I made prior.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: try to use 2 view http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp and work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like :

```
SELECT
    Email,
    Domain,
    site.SiteID,
    site.SiteName,
    Status,
    LastLogin,
    up.UPID,
    up.UPName,
    trd.TRMCID,
    trd.TRMCName,
    cinfo.CountryCode,
    cntry.Country
FROM UserDetails as ud
    INNER JOIN UltimateParent up on ud.UPID = up.UPID
    INNER JOIN TRMCDetails trd on ud.TRMCID = trd.TRMCID
    INNER JOIN CountryInfo cinfo on cntry.CountryCode = cinfo.CountryCode
    INNER JOIN SiteLocation site on ud.SiteID = site.SiteID
    INNER JOIN Country cntry on cntry.CountryCode = site.CountryCode
```

Comment: This worked! Now I understand where I made my mistake. Thanks, Man!

Comment: Most Welcome Joshua...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your 2nd query as a subquery. Hope I understood well what you are looking for.

```
SELECT Email, Domain, site.SiteID, site.SiteName, Status, LastLogin, up.UPID, up.UPName, trd.TRMCID, trd.TRMCName, s1.Country
FROM UserDetails as ud
INNER JOIN SiteLocation as site
on ud.SiteID = site.SiteID
INNER JOIN UltimateParent as up
on ud.UPID = up.UPID
INNER JOIN TRMCDetails as trd
on ud.TRMCID = trd.TRMCID
INNER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT SiteID, cinfo.CountryCode, Country
  From Country as cntry
  INNER JOIN CountryInfo as cinfo
  on cntry.CountryCode = cinfo.CountryCode

  INNER JOIN SiteLocation as site2
  on cntry.CountryCode = site2.CountryCode
) s1 on s1.SiteID = site.SiteID
```

Comment: This is the first solution I was trying to make. I just got it wrong on the subquery  part. Kinda got confused. Thanks for this!